# How do I make my program give me the value of a certain cell in a CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I am having problems with trying to make my program find a certain cell in a CSV file. My program will ask you for a 8 digit number. If it is in the CSV file, the row should be written to a text file. It then should proceed to ask the user how much of the product they want to buy. This quantity will then be multiplied to give a final price. The price will be written to a variable named totalPrice.

My initial problem is with the quantity since I cannot retrieve it from the third column of the row of the entered GTIN-8 number in my CSV file.

My code is:

```
import csv
import sys
import re
import os

addItem = ""
gtinNum = ""
quantity = 0
totalPrice = 0
restart = ""

f = open("ChocolateCSV.csv", "rt")

def restart():
    restart = input("Would you like to restart? Y/N")

    if restart.lower() == "y":
        gtinQuestion()
    else:
        print(receiptCont)
        sys.exit()

def quantityQuestion():
    quantity = input("How much would you like?")


def scanGTIN():
    global rows
    rows = re.split('\n', f.read())
    global receiptCont
    receiptCont = receipt.read()

   for index, row in enumerate(rows):
        global cells
        cells = row.split(',')
        if gtinNum in cells:
            receipt.write(receiptCont)
            receipt.close()
            quantityQuestion()

def gtinQuestion():
    global gtinNum
    global receipt
    receipt = open("receipt.txt", "r+")
    gtinNum = input("Please enter the GTIN-8 Code of the product you would like to order:")

    if gtinNum.isdigit() == False or len(gtinNum) != 8:
        gtinQuestion()
    elif gtinNum.isdigit() == True and len(gtinNum) == 8:
        scanGTIN()


gtinQuestion()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just iterate through the lines of the csv file and return a particular column of the row that contains the 8 digit number:

```
import csv

def get_row(filename, number, column):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f):
            if str(number) in row:
                return row[column+1]
```

Comment: This is for some schoolwork at school, so the first solution may be better than the one using Pandas. Although, Pandas looks like the better option. Let me have a look at the first solution.

Comment: I think I misread the question initially. Something like this would likely be more appropriate to get the row in the csv file that you need.

Comment: I get the error    _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?) when running

Comment: What version of python are you using? Try replacing `'rb'` with `'r'` in the `open` function.

Comment: It doesnt give the error with 'r', but I want to get the value in the third column of that row (or the value after the second comma) @pbreach

Comment: No problem, just index `row` to get the third element with `row[2]`. I'll update.